# Contemporary definition of Sexual Predator

Tags: meaning, contemporary-english

I keep hearing this word, but I have a hard time pinning it down. Sometimes it seem to only be used when rape or sexual assault is involved, but not always.

Wikipedia says:

> A sexual predator is a person seen as obtaining or trying to obtain sexual contact with another person in a metaphorically "predatory" or abusive manner.

I am not sure what "predator" and "abusive" means specifically, but it goes on to say (emphasis mine):

> People who commit sex crimes, such as rape or child sexual abuse, are commonly referred to as sexual predators, particularly in tabloid media or as a **power phrase** by politicians.

I have also heard it used to describe, what I would call flirting, with no legal ramifications. It seems to be used across a wide spectrum. Since it is used as a *Power Phrase*, does it have a political definition?

Does an official definition exist? Maybe from the body of law?

<sub>If not official, are there good ways to find out how people use it?</sub>

EDIT:

Example from *Interpersonal Skills Exchange*

> Then He asked me that if I had had one night stands and I told him, "No". And after a while with a lot of build up (like can I ask you something? Don't tell anyone that I asked you this) he asks me if I was still a virgin? I was taken aback. He then wants to know why to which I reply that I am waiting for my special someone. He goes on to make fun of that.

This is the example that got me thinking about it, when someone called it *predatory behavior*, which I admittedly don't know is the same a being a *Sexual Predator*. From Merriam Webster's definition, there is no violence here, only words.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69940/discussion-on-question-by-chris-wohlert-contemporary-definition-of-sexual-predat).

Comment: Post comments here only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Avoid answering questions in comments. Other types of comment can be posted in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or the chatroom created for the purpose.